# see open webpage in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, putty

I typed below command in Putty but nothing happened. I am new to Ubuntu and would like to need how I can see the opened webpage. Thanks.

`google-chrome www.google.com`

Comment: Did you type that into putty, or into the terminal?

Comment: @Randomhero  I typed in putty. I do not know how to access the terminal, nor do I have a desktop for Linux. All I have is putty for command and WinSCP. Would be much appreciated for your input on how to efficiently use Linux.

Comment: If you are just using putty, then you will be unable to run google chrome. That will require a GUI to run. 
You might have some luck trying something like this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome but that might be a little advanced for you at the moment

Comment: @Randomhero Yes indeed. I do not quite understand the content in the link. Start with Putty, how can I install desktops like GNOME?

Comment: You can't run GNOME or other desktops easily through ssh via putty. How have you got it installed at the moment? It would be easier to learn those sort of things if you have a screen and a keyboard attached to the linux computer

Comment: @Randomhero  It is Ubuntu server provided by the company I am working for. It is used over Windows. I have no clue how it was initially installed.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a post that solved this question after a week's detour and struggling.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server